# Android Studio added extra drawable

Tags: android-studio, merge

Android Studio 2.2 added extra drawable which I do not use at all to my APK. I do not like it, because it increased size of APK.

[image]

I compile following libs:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

How to remove extra drawables (all you can see on picture)?
Picture is from Android Studio 2.2 APK viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way you might want to do it is to use a terminal and change into the res/drawable/ folder(there is a drawable folder in the regular directory of each project, and there is another drawable under ~/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/~)/another one is depending on your platform(~/Android/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/data/res/drawable-xhdpi/~) you are the one who knows the drawables you dont need, list the items there and remove the ones you don't think you need. I don't think you can access the drawable folder from the top level SDK manager to uninstall it. That can only work if you knew the exact package to uninstall that contains the drawables. 
My two cents!